# Load url in WKWebView when notification is opened

Tags: swiftui, onesignal

I'm sending push notification's with OneSignal, I'm receiving them fine. My problem is, is that when I click on the notification, I'd like it to open the notification url. I have the notificationUrl, but loading the url in my WKWebView is my problem. I am using SwiftUi App lifecycle, and not UiKit. So take in note that I don't have a ViewController.

I've tried using `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: notificationUrl)!)` but this opens the link in the browser.

Here's my notification opened handler in AppDelegate.

```
      .....

      let osNotificationOpenedBlock: OSNotificationOpenedBlock = { resultObj in
      let notification: OSNotification = resultObj.notification
      let actionType = resultObj.action.type
      let dataObj = resultObj.notification.additionalData
      let notificationUrl = "\(dataObj?["notificationUrl"] ?? "")"
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: notificationUrl)!)
      }

      OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(osNotificationOpenedBlock)
      ....
```

Comment: Store the URL in a `@Published` property of an `ObservableObject` that gets passed down to your `View` hierarchy (using `.environmentObject`, for example). Then, wherever you want it displayed, display a web view if that `@Published` property is `!= nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me, is to make the webview variable a global variable in the code. So in WebView.swift or your webview file, put the `WKWebView` variable on the outside of the struct and apply:

```
var wbWebViewEl: WKWebView = WKWebView()
struct SwiftUiWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
...
```

Then, instead of:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: notificationUrl)!)
```

Do:

```
var notificationRequestEl = URLRequest(url: url!)
wbWebViewEl.load(notificationRequestEl)
```