# Pull to refresh for WKWebView

Tags: ios, swiftui, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to add pull to refresh on my `wkwebview` app. I'm using `UIViewRepresentable` for my webview, so I don't have the `onViewLoad` function and view controllers. Here's my code:

```
var wbWebViewEl: WKWebView = WKWebView()
struct SwiftUiWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    ....
    class refreshWebViewClass {
    @objc func refreshWebView1(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("test debug :D")
        wbWebViewEl.reload()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        sender.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {    
        ......
        wbWebViewEl.scrollView.bounces = true
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebViewClass.refreshWebView1), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        wbWebViewEl.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        wbWebViewEl.scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        .....
    }

    .....

}
```

At the moment, when you swipe down, it shows the refresh loading spinner, but it doesn't stop spinning. Also the test print I put in the `refreshWebView1` function, doesn't show in the logcat. Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong here? If you need to see anymore code let me know :)

Comment: Looks like your `refreshWebViewClass` (please consider using the standard Swift naming conventions of capitalizing types) should be a `Coordinator`. Then, in your `addTarget`, the target would be `context.coordinator`, not `self`, which doesn't make sense here, since `self` doesn't actually implement this method. `wbWebViewEl` should be a property of `SwiftUiWebView` or just created in `makeUIView`.

Comment: @jnpdx I put the refresh function in a coordinator, and changed the target to `context.coordinator`, and it worked! It now reloads when I swipe down on the page. And as for the bad function names, I've changed them now. I've kept `wbWebViewEl` where it is since I use it elsewhere in my code, I asked a  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568090/load-url-in-wkwebview-when-notification-is-opened/70367158#70367158) on it too. Also If you'd like, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `refreshWebViewClass` should be a `Coordinator`. Then, in your `addTarget`, the target would be `context.coordinator`, not `self`, which doesn't make sense here, since self doesn't actually implement this method.